# How to get the new data, when listening for changes at specific Firestore doc?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get the new data, when something in a Firestore Doc changes (example Doc: "1234" in collection: "games"). Do I need to listen for updates with this code:

```
var doc = db.collection('games').doc('1234');

var observer = doc.onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {
  console.log(`Received doc snapshot: ${docSnapshot}`);
  // ...
}, err => {
  console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
});
```

and then just run a function to get the new data where the

```
   // ...
```

is?

I tried to get the data with docSnapshot.data, but there just seems to be some info about firebase stuff, like the doc, that updated...

Is there a better way to do this, than what I showed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct; to listen to a document's changes you should use the `onSnapshot` method on a given collection. To use your example:

```
db.collection('games').doc('1234').onSnapshot(doc => {
  console.log(`Received data:`, doc.data());
}, err => {
  console.log(`Encountered error:`, err);
});
```

Comment: OK, thanks. How would I implement this in my code? At the moment I registered a method, that just gets the whole doc, in the methods part and then I call it every second, in the created hook, but I exceeded my quota rather quickly

Comment: @TheSleepyOwl Just execute this code, e.g. in the `created` hook and that's it. You don't need to call it several time, only once. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen